# .ncb file not getting craeted in VS 2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am using VS 2005 for a project . But my .ncb file is missing . Can you please suggest what i have to do to ?

Comment: If I'm in your case, I'd rather create a new project rather than to tinker with the project's filesystem.

Comment: VS should regenerate the .ncb file when you re-start (in fact, when browsing gets messed up, you quit, delete the .ncb file, then re-start VS to get it re-generated and straighten out browing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you mension is IntelliSense in Visual Studio 2005.
You could follow the troubleshooting steps provided from Microsoft MSDN.

To regenerate .ncb files

1. Delete the .ncb file from your solution.
2. Rebuild your solution.

If you encoutering some error. You can check

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235519(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try Tools->Import and Export Settings->Reset all settings and restart your VS editor.

Comment: MSDN says: To turn IntelliSense options OFF by default: On the **Tools** menu, click **Options**. Select the **Text Editor** folder. Select the folder for the language you want to customize IntelliSense. In the General property page, clear check boxes for IntelliSense features that you do not want: **Auto list members** applies to List Members, **Parameter information** applies to Parameter Info

Comment: I have followed the above steps . But still its not working .
project->update IntelliSense  option is missing .

Comment: Nowhere in my comments I have mentioned project->update IntelliSense option. Please follow the steps carefully. Basically you would need to check **Auto list members** and **Parameter information** in your case if it is unchecked. Otherwise search on MSDN, you will find the answer.

Comment: Auto list members and Parameter information is checked . But still i am not getting IntelliSense  .
What i stated is after checking the above option update IntelliSense menu item shall be displayed inside the project .

Comment: Then I guess you need to spend some time on researching over this issue. Just ensure your solution is not opened twice because in this case formerly opened solution will show intellisense details while later one will not.